# How to cast to array in TypeScript 2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting, typescript2.0

I had some code that cast an object to type array (so I could use array functions on the object without compile errors).

```
    var n = (result.data['value'] as []).map( (a)=>{
      //..
    });
```

But on upgrade to ts2, I get:

> error TS1122: A tuple type element list cannot be empty.

Which is actually a syntax error, claiming you forgot a comma or value. So, how do I modify this cast to work correctly?

I tried `as [IMyType]` and it worked, but I'd prefer not to specify type since I only need the `array.prototype` functions here... also, I don't think that's how you actually do it.

Comment: What's the type of `result.data['value']`?

Comment: it's just a simple array.

Comment: I mean, I could cast it to my final type [IWhatever] but I don't feel that's necessary here, I just want to use the array methods.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For some reason the compiler thinks that `result.data['value']` [is a tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) and not an array.

You can cast it like this:

```
result.data['value'] as any[]
```

Which should tell the compiler that it's an array, or:

```
result.data['value'] as Array<any>
```

---

If your array has only items of type `IMyType` then simply:

```
result.data['value'] as IMyType[]
```

However, if your array contains items of different types then it's either a `any[]` or a tuple, for example:

```
result.data['value'] as [IMyType, string, string]
```

In any case, in the compiled js it will be an array, but tuples let you define a fixed length arrays with specific types.

Answer (score 9):

You're not casting to an array.

`[string]` is a tuple with a single element `string`.

`[string, string]` is a tuple with two elements, `string` and `string`.

`[]` is a tuple with zero elements.

The syntax for an array of strings is `string[]`

What you likely want is `result.data['value'] as any[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the previous cast syntax options mentioned above, you can also do the following:

```
var n = (<SampleType[]>result.data['value']).map((a) => {
    //..
});
```